# Automatically execute data toggle in combination with href Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

First thank you for reading this, and i would like to apologize if this is a duplicate question.

I am working with bootstrap, and I like to use the Dynamic Pills

I got every working fine like the example on w3schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_pills_dynamic&stacked=h

I was wondering if it is possible to have an autoloop in jQuery/javascript that it will automatically go through the tabs

I tried to use the following for just to activate 1 off the tabs when the loading the page

```css
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#menu3').pills("show");
    });
</script>
```

```html
<title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Pills</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Help would be really appreciated, because I am really a noob!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to loop through the nav-pills use the `setInterval`
https://jsfiddle.net/fq80o54c/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
    function changeTags() {
        # your code to change the tags
    }
    setTimeout(changeTags(), 2000);
```

This would be harder to implement. Maybe a better and much easier would be to modify and use Carousel from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)